# Make HTML visible inside Iframe

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making my own WYSIWYG. I've got two buttons: "Visualize" and Show Source.

I've got an iframe (rich text editor) that contains a huge piece of HTML code. First time it's loaded it shows all the elements visually. Once Show Source is pressed the innerHTML text (of the visualized html) is shown. But how can I make the HTML text visual again, when the Visualize button is pressed?

`content.document.body.innerText` holds the HTML that needs to be visualized. 
(content = id of the iframe)

```
$('#Visualize').click(function()
{
   // Make HTML visible
});
```

Comment: What's your Show Source code?

Comment: Basically shows the HTML source code of the preview

Comment: er... if you want specific answers (cf. your comment below) you'll need to be more specific too

Comment: I got HTML code inside content.document.body.innerText. content here the id of my iframe. How do I visualize the html code inside content.document.body.innerText inside the same frame? That should be what you need to know ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using an iframe and that iframe is only intended to hold the actual page source being edited, then you're going to need variables on your parent frame that hold the actual source. I would recommend keeping it separate and then use the following to perform switches:

```
var actualSource = content.document.body.innerHTML;
// just something to initialize it
// You should probably keep it in a global object instead of as a var


$('#Visualize').click(function()
{
   actualSource = content.document.body.innerText;
   content.document.body.innerHTML = "";
   content.document.body.innerHTML= actualSource;
});
```

I would imagine that you have methods that are capturing the source, but I would imagine you'd want to capture the actual source as it is at that moment. I'm not sure what you're doing with the actual editing piece (is it a div that is editable? is it a text area?), but in order to perform the showing, it should just be a matter of toggling the innerHTML and innerText between the two settings. The real catch will be monitoring the actual controls affected by this change.

Comment: Thanks dude, I didnt know resetting the source would visualize it. That was the answer to my question =)

Answer (score 4):

With the html code that you already have you and to show a preview in a div, correct? Just use the [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function.

```
$('#Visualize').click(function(){
   $('#myShowDiv').html(content.document.body.innerText);
});
```

Comment: what if myShowDiv is an iframe?

Comment: @user1534664: Then the relevant question would be: Why would you use an iframe in the first place?

Comment: @JoelEtherton try making a WYSIWYG yourself and you'll find out ;) Basically an iframe has a seperate focus. If its a div instead, the focus would dissapear as soon as you press one of the buttons inside the control panel and the button's function wouldn't know what to edit.

Comment: In such a situation you could either get yourself into a huge heap of work, or use the API rangy, or go the easy way: use an iframe.